# Spread every other row then unite to append row names in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am in the process of trying to make untidy data data. I have data in the following format:

```
name    x
a       NA
value   1 
b       NA
value   2
c       NA
value   3
```

I would like it to be in the following format

```
name      x
a_value   1 
b_value   2
c_value   3
```

How can I do this in dplyr?

My first thought is to come up with a way to `spread` so that

```
name    name2        x    x2
a       value       NA     1
b       value       NA     2
c       value       NA     3
```

From there I know I can use `unite` for `name` and `name2` and delete column `x`, but I am not sure if `spread` can produce the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group on NA and summarise, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(grp = cumsum(is.na(x))) %>% 
 summarise(name = paste(name, collapse = '_'))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>       grp name   
>     <int> <chr>  
> 1     1 a_value
> 2     2 b_value
> 3     3 c_value
> ```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(name = c("a", "value", "b", "value", "c", "value"
), x = c(NA, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 3L)), .Names = c("name", "x"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `na.locf` and then remove the unwanted rows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

DF %>% 
   mutate(x = na.locf(x, fromLast = TRUE)) %>% 
   filter(name != "value")
```

giving:

```
  name x
1    a 1
2    b 2
3    c 3
```

### Note

```
DF <- 
structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "value"), class = "factor"), x = c(NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 
NA, 3L)), .Names = c("name", "x"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```